# Why the ASUS Transformer Prime is the only device that have an OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: android, out-of-memory, tablet, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm working on an Android application that needs to display 4 big bitmaps (6 x screen size). At the beginning, I've problem with that but with code optimization on memory management that works on whole devices. But on ASUS Transformer Prime in 4.0.3 android version, I've a OutOfMemory error. It's very strange because the Heap Size seems to be to 256Mb. A lot compare to other devices on which it runs correctly.

We have activated Large Heap and deactivated Hardware accelerated.

Have you an idea of our problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your screen is 1280x800, therefore a screen-sized 32bpp bitmap will require just under 4MB, and a 6 x screen size bitmap will need 23.5MB. And you want four of those... that's 93.75MB.

The process heap limit varies from device to device but I'd consider 64MB to be a lot (perhaps I'm behind the times). 256MB is huge!

IMHO you shouldn't be trying to keep such massive bitmaps in memory at all. You'd be better off breaking them up into tiles that are no bigger than the screen and loading the tiles as they are needed.

Alternatively, try using 16bpp images or allocating the space for your massive bitmaps in JNI (i.e. in C) and bypass the Java heap management entirely.

Comment: We don't need 4 bitmap of 6 x screen height but only one. Others are smaller. Those 4 bitmaps must be loaded at the same time because they are displayed and animated between themselves. It's very curious that dosen't generate an exception on a device similar (résolution, size) at the PRIME but with less Heap Size memory.

Comment: Possibly you should try enforcing 16bpp when opening the bitmap.